# New to VSCODE on Mac, how stop terminal from printing out directory/env?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Mac and just installed miniforge and VSCode for arm64.

I did a simple test to print hello world in python and ended up with long text for the directory or environment that python 3 is being run from.

```
(base) username@username-MBP 07 Code %  cd "/Users/username/Documents/07 Code" ; /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.192408
7327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 53352 -- "/Users/username/Documents/07 Code/hello.py"
```

How do I trim or remove the text?

I tried opening the settings.json file and it's read only for some reason... never had this problem on windows.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very sorry for being late.

You are debugging the python file, you can change the value of `"console"` to `"internalConsole"` in the lanuch.json file.

Or you can execute the python file through right-click and select `Run Python File in Terminal`(click the run-button on the top-right).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I couldn't locate the launch.json file. Is this within Python itesel of special settings within the python distribution?